# How to get date of Month in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to get a specific date in SQL using the following scenarios;

The date is the 20th:

1. if the date of the current month is the 23rd January 2017 then I would like to get everything from the 20th January 2017 i.e. 3 days
2. if the date of the current month is the 17th January 2017 then I would like to get everything from the 20th December 2016.

So the focus is the 20th of the current month or the previous month based on the current date.

Any ideas on how to structure this in SQL?

Comment: Whats DBMS are you using? Also what is your date column like? Please give an example

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (Many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant when it comes to date/time.) Also add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Also what about if the date is the 20th, is that previous or next months data?

Comment: SQL Server is the DBMS

Comment: If the date = 20th then use the current 20th of the current month; if the date is the 19th then get everything from the 20th of the previous month..

Comment: Please edit your question to include the relevant tables DDL, some sample date as DML, and desired results.\

Answer (score 0):

This expression should find the most recent 20th of the month that is in the past:

```
select
    DATEADD(month,
        DATEDIFF(month,'20010101',GETDATE()),
        CASE WHEN DATEPART(day,GETDATE()) < 20  THEN '20001220'
                                                ELSE '20010120' END)
```

It works by computing the whole number of months between some fixed date in the past and today.

We then add that number of months onto another fixed date - the 20th of a month. But we use `CASE` to decide what relationship this second fixed date has compared to the first - is it the same month or the previous one?

Answer (score 0):

You can always use `MONTH(date field)` to get the numeric value of the date's month and you can just do -1 for previous month, `YEAR(date field)` works the same way.

Answer (score 0):

I usually build some function for this kind of operations, it can change in time and it is easily modificable.

```
CREATE FUNCTION GetDates(@Day int)
RETURNS @DateRange TABLE
(
    StartDate DATETIME,
    EndDate DATETIME
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StartDate VARCHAR(30),
            @EndDate VARCHAR(30),
            @CurDate DATETIME,
            @CurDay INT;

    SET @CurDate = GETDATE();
    SET @CurDay = DAY(GETDATE());
    SET @EndDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), @CurDate, 112);

    IF @CurDay <= @Day
    BEGIN
        SET @StartDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), DATEADD(day, (@Day - @CurDay), DATEADD(month, -1, @CurDate)), 112);
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @StartDate = CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), DATEADD(day, (@Day - @CurDay), @CurDate), 112);
    END

    INSERT INTO @DateRange VALUES (CAST(@StartDate AS DATETIME), CAST(@EndDate AS DATETIME));
    RETURN
END
GO
```

Then you can add it to a join sentence, or call it directly using a select sentence like:

```
select StartDate, EndDate from GetDates(14);
```

Can try it [here](http://rextester.com/DPZBW40583).